# Google Fit: API gets only details of datasources but not the details of calories in nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-fit, google-api-nodejs-client

I am only getting the details of the dataSources, but I am not getting the calories burned from google fit. How its possible to get the details of calories burned.
I can get this information from ([Google Fitness API returns only {} as result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498652/google-fitness-api-returns-only-as-result)) this code like the below one but not the Activity information.

```
Request:
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.calories.consumed:merge_calories_expended?access_token=88888888888888888888

Response:
{ dataStreamId: 'derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.calories.consumed:merge_calories_expended',
       dataStreamName: 'merge_calories_expended',
       type: 'derived',
       dataType: [Object],
       application: [Object] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the available datasources by sending GET request to 
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources

Looking at the result I can see a dataSource id "derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:platform_calories_expended"

Using that in the URL, I get the calories dataset:
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:platform_calories_expended/datasets/1451606400000000000-1455888676947965751

Resulting:

```
   {
    "minStartTimeNs"=>"1451606400000000000",
    "maxEndTimeNs"=>"1455888676947965751",
    "dataSourceId"=>
 "derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:platform_calories_expended",
 "point"=>
  [{"startTimeNanos"=>"1455883200000000000",
    "endTimeNanos"=>"1455883500000000000",
    "dataTypeName"=>"com.google.calories.expended",
    "originDataSourceId"=>
"derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_activities",
    "value"=>[{"fpVal"=>5.666666507720947}],
    "modifiedTimeMillis"=>"1455888999993"}]}
```

Also see the note at https://support.google.com/fit/?hl=en#6075066

> Note: To see the distance you've gone or how many calories you've burned, you'll need to fill out your height, weight, and gender.

Comment: From the above result, how we can get the step count. Is that I need to write separate code to calculate calories burned from startTime and endTime.